# Explain a linear function property?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis

Let $C(x)$ a linear function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Then we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
C\left(S_0^1\right)&=C\left( \frac{y_m-r}{y_m-y_1}S_0^1+\frac{r-y_1}{y_m-y_1}S_0^1 \right) \\
&=\frac{y_m-r}{y_m-y_1}C\left( \frac{1+y_1}{1+r}S_0^1 \right)+\frac{r-y_1}{y_m-y_1}C \left( \frac{1+y_m}{1+r}S_0^1 \right),
\end{align*}
$$

for $S_0^1>0,y_1<0<r<y_m$.

The first equality follows by linearity of $C$ and

$$\frac{y_m-r}{y_m-1},\frac{r-y_1}{y_m-y_1}>0 \, \operatorname{with} \,\frac{y_m-r}{y_m-y_1}+\frac{r-y_1}{y_m-y_1}=1.$$

(some weighted average).

***Question: Why holds the second equality?***

Intuitively I think we have a weighted average of some convex combination of a linear function, but I am not able to formally understand it, maybe you can show it.

For $y_m=-y_1$ the second equality is true as it adds to zero, but the general case $y_1<0<r<y_m$ I could not show.

It would be here sufficient to show, since $C$ is linear:

$
\frac{y_m-r}{y_m-y_1}\frac{1+y_1}{1+r}+\frac{r-y_1}{y_m-y_1}\frac{1+y_m}{1+r}=1
$

It may be that the condition $y_1=-y_m$ was forgotten, in which case you may easily contradict the equality by showing some fit numerical counterexample for $y_1\neq-y_m$ with $y_1<0<r<y_m$...

Comment: Do you mean "Why does it hold for the second inequality"? Since the second inequality, $y \lt 0$, is part of a sufficient condition not a consequence.

Comment: The last display is $AC(S)$ with $$(y_m-y_1)(1+r)A=(y_m-r)(1+y_1)+(r-y_1)(1+y_m)$$ What happens when you multiply everything out and combine like terms?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I multiplied out the terms in the second equality but didnt see how it would fit. Apparently you can take out the fraction before $S_0^1$ aswell and it should sum to $1$ together, but I didnt find it.

Comment: But did you multiply out the right side in the display in my comment?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I put an edit to the question, please check the last paragraph..

Comment: Since you refuse to multiply things out, I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$(y_m-r)(1+y_1)+(r-y_1)(1+y_m)=y_m+y_1y_m-r-ry_1+r+ry_m-y_1-y_1y_m\\=y_m-ry_1+ry_m-y_1=y_m(1+r)-y_1(1+r)=(y_m-y_1)(1+r)$$ so $${y_m-r\over y_m-y_1}{1+y_1\over1+r}+{r-y_1\over y_m-y_1}{1+y_m\over1+r}=1$$ Q.E.D.